# Three.js render to texture

Tags: three.js

I'm fighting some unexpected behavior.

It seems that i can't get anything to render to target.

```
renderer.render( scene , cam , renderTarget , false ); // does not work, empty target
```

either one of these though, will fill the target, this one though renders to frame buffer once

```
renderer.render( scene , cam , renderTarget , false );
renderer.render( scene , cam ); //this somehow causes the renderTarget to be filled
```

or this:

```
renderer.setRenderTarget( renderTarget );
renderer.render( scene , cam , renderTarget , false );
renderer.setRenderTarget( null );
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I render to a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget:

```
var pickingScene = new THREE.Scene();
var pickingTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(renderer.domElement.clientWidth, renderer.domElement.clientHeight);
pickingTexture.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

renderer.render(pickingScene, camera, pickingTexture);
```

Comment: Thats how it should work. but mine doesnt, which version is this?

Comment: @pailhead that works on r79 and r78. What errors are you getting?

Comment: it just doesnt work, i don't get any errors but i don't get data in the texture. It's mostly failing with the PMREM generator, i have to add the stuff from the question. I get that another draw call fixes it and forces it to be rendered, but i don't understand why. The source seems to be handling this correctly, i have no idea why making these calls manually fixes it.