# How could we get the pixel's color of a mesh when we click on it, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

Currently in the page we have a mesh loaded with TreeJS and displayed in a canvas:
[image]

***How could we get the color of the point where we click on?***

I have tried as it has been suggested here: [Getting the color value of a pixel on click of a mesh with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583012/getting-the-color-value-of-a-pixel-on-click-of-a-mesh-with-three-js) , to create a canvas with a 2d context on top of the one using webgl context.

The problem is that when we convert the model to PNG, the image is white:

Our img 2d src:

[image]

If we click on it:

[image]

So then the console logs that the color is: `0 0 0 0`

Also I will show the code where we generate the webgl canvas and the 2d canvas:

```
// this class handles the load and the canva for a nrrd
// Using programming based on prototype: https://javascript.info/class
// This class should be improved:
//   - Canvas Width and height

InitCanvas = function (IdDiv, Filename) {


    this.IdDiv = IdDiv;
    this.Filename = Filename
}

InitCanvas.prototype = {

    constructor: InitCanvas,

    init: function () {

        this.container = document.getElementById(this.IdDiv);

        // this should be changed.
        this.container.innerHeight = 600;
        this.container.innerWidth = 800;

        //These statements should be changed to improve the image position
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.container.innerWidth / this.container.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
        this.camera.position.z = 300;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(this.camera);

        // light

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);


        // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            this.container.innerWidth = sliceZ.iLength;
            this.container.innerHeight = sliceZ.jLength;

            sliceZ.mesh.material.color.setRGB(0,1,1);


            console.log('Our slice is: ', sliceZ);

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
        }.bind(this));


        this.scene = scene;



        var canvas2d = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas2d.id = "canvas2D";
        canvas2d.style.width = `${this.container.innerWidth}px`;
        canvas2d.style.height = `${this.container.innerHeight}px`;
        canvas2d.style.zIndex = 8;




        this.container.appendChild(canvas2d);





        // renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.container.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.innerWidth, this.container.innerHeight);

        // add canvas in container
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);





    },

    animate: function () {

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

}
```

Also we use it in the logic.js

```
if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

// global variables for this scripts
let OriginalImg,
    SegmentImg,
    myFileReader;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mousePressed = false;
var clickCount = 0;
var allText;


init();
animate();


// initilize the page
function init() {


    readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt");

    let originalImgPath = getParameterByName('originalImgPath');
    let filename = originalImgPath || "models/nrrd/columna02.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    let idDiv = 'original';
    OriginalImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    OriginalImg.init();
    console.log(OriginalImg);

    let segmentedImgPath = getParameterByName('segmentedImgPath');

    filename = segmentedImgPath || "models/nrrd/columnasegmentado02.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    idDiv = 'segment';
    SegmentImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    SegmentImg.init();
    

    let canvas2D = document.getElementById('canvas2D');
    let ctx2D = canvas2D.getContext('2d');

    var img2D = new Image();
    img2D.src = OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.toDataURL("img/png");
    console.log('Our img 2d source is:::: ',img2D.src);
    img2D.addEventListener("load", function () {
        ctx2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2D.width, canvas2D.height);
        ctx2D.drawImage(img2D, 0, 0);
        // from here, get your pixel data
        var imgData = ctx2D.getImageData(10, 10, 1, 1);
        red = imgData.data[0];
        green = imgData.data[1];
        blue = imgData.data[2];
        alpha = imgData.data[3];
        console.log(red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha);
    });
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

let originalCanvas = document.getElementById('original');
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);


function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    mousePressed = true;

    clickCount++;

    let realClickedCanvasX = event.offsetX;
    let realClickedCanvasY = event.offsetY;

    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( ( event.clientY - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1


    console.log('Mouse x position is: ', realClickedCanvasX, 'the click number was: ', clickCount);
    console.log('Mouse x position is: ', realClickedCanvasY, 'the click number was: ', clickCount);

    //console.log('Mouse x position is: ', mouse.x, 'the click number was: ', clickCount);
    //console.log('Mouse Y position is: ', mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse.clone(), OriginalImg.camera);
    var objects = raycaster.intersectObjects(OriginalImg.scene.children);

    console.log(objects);
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    mousePressed = false
}


function animate() {


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    OriginalImg.animate();
    SegmentImg.animate();


}
```

I have also read:

- [ThreeJS How to pick the intersection point color of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433305/threejs-how-to-pick-the-intersection-point-color-of-an-object)
- [Get pixel color from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789076/get-pixel-color-from-an-image)
- [How to check if a specific pixel of an image is transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)
- [Get a pixel from HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)
- https://johnresig.com/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/
- https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-canvas-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation
- [Get the mouse coordinates when clicking on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172115/get-the-mouse-coordinates-when-clicking-on-canvas)
- [HTML5 Dynamically create Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652513/html5-dynamically-create-canvas)
- [Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5)
- [Set Canvas size using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251480/set-canvas-size-using-javascript)

Thank you for your help, in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you @TheJim01 for your help.

I have tried your suggestion, and with the following code:

Into OnDocumentMouseDown function:

```
var target = OriginalImg.renderer.getRenderTarget();
    console.log('Our target which should be a WebGLRenderTarget is: ');
    console.log(target);

    var outputBuffer = new Uint8Array( OriginalImg.renderer.width * OriginalImg.renderer.height * 4 );

    OriginalImg.renderer.readRenderTargetPixels ( target, 0, 0, OriginalImg.renderer.width, OriginalImg.renderer.height, outputBuffer );

    var pixelIndex = ((realClickedCanvasX * OriginalImg.renderer.width) + realClickedCanvasY) * 4;

    var color = {
        r: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 0],
        g: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 1],
        b: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 2],
        a: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 3]
    };

    console.log('Color of clicked pixel is: ');
    console.log(color);
```

We see in the web console:

```
Our target which should be a WebGLRenderTarget is: 

null

THREE.WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels: renderTarget is not THREE.WebGLRenderTarget.

Color of clicked pixel is: 

Object { r: undefined, g: undefined, b: undefined, a: undefined }
```

I tried to understand what happened and to solve this I read:

[Three.js render to texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583219/three-js-render-to-texture)

And I added a WebGlRenderTarget as:

```
... more code...

    this.renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth, this.renderer.domElement.clientHeight);
    
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera, this.renderTarget);

... more code...
```

And now we see in our web console:

```
    Error: WebGL warning: clear: Framebuffer not complete. (status: 0x8cd6) COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 has no width or height
    three.js:21370:4
    Error: WebGL warning: clear: Framebuffer must be complete.
    three.js:21370:4
    Error: WebGL warning: clear: Framebuffer not complete. (status: 0x8cd6) COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 has no width or height
    three.js:21370:4
    Error: WebGL warning: clear: Framebuffer must be complete.
    three.js:21370:4
  ...
```

I have tried to look for it and I have seen this issue in GitHub:

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/3767

However I do not see it could be related.

EDIT2:

**Thank you @TheJim01 for your help, I appreciate it!!
With your help and code the Render Target issue looks like it is solved. In fact I see a strange warning in the web console:**

> Error: WebGL warning: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.

After searching for this warning, I saw this great topic: [Error: WebGL: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800600/error-webgl-exceeded-16-live-webgl-contexts-for-this-principal-losing-the-lea)

And after closing the tab, and reloading the project it has disappeared.

***In addition, the colors we obtain are undefined, I will show a console log:***

```
Our OriginalImg where we want to get the color is: 

Object { IdDiv: "original", Filename: "models/nrrd/columna02.nrrd", container: div#original.column, camera: {…}, scene: {…}, renderer: {…} }

Error: WebGL warning: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.

Error: WebGL warning: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.

The target being used in this click is: 

Object { uuid: "8EAEFD8F-5C55-4973-84BC-471D43C006F8", width: undefined, height: undefined, scissor: {…}, scissorTest: false, viewport: {…}, texture: {…}, depthBuffer: true, stencilBuffer: true, depthTexture: null }

Our target which should be a WebGLRenderTarget is: 
onMouseDownLogic.js:23:5
Object { uuid: "8EAEFD8F-5C55-4973-84BC-471D43C006F8", width: 800, height: 600, scissor: {…}, scissorTest: false, viewport: {…}, texture: {…}, depthBuffer: true, stencilBuffer: true, depthTexture: null, … }
onMouseDownLogic.js:24:5
Color of clicked pixel is: 
onMouseDownLogic.js:39:5
{…}
​
a: undefined
​
b: undefined
​
g: undefined
​
r: undefined
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

**To help better understand what I am writing about I refactored the code to better explain and write it.**

We have logic.js which aims is to initialize canvas and animate them:

```
if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

// global variables for this scripts
let OriginalImg,
    SegmentImg;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var allText;

init();
animate();

// initilize the page
function init() {

    readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt");
    OriginalImg = initCanvasOfOriginalImg();
    initCanvasOfSegmentedImg();

}

let originalCanvas = document.getElementById('original');
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

// re-usable objects defined outside your mouse event
console.log('Our OriginalImg where we want to get the color is: ');
console.log(OriginalImg);

var size = OriginalImg.renderer.getSize();
var reusableTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(OriginalImg.renderer.width, OriginalImg.renderer.height);

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

    let {realClickedCanvasX, realClickedCanvasY} = calculateClickedPointWindowCoordinates(event);
    let OriginalImgRenderer = calculateNormalizedClickedPointCoordinates(event);


    var target = OriginalImgRenderer.getRenderTarget() || reusableTarget;
    console.log('The target being used in this click is: ');
    console.log(target);

    size = OriginalImgRenderer.getSize();
    target.setSize(size.width, size.height);

    OriginalImgRenderer.render( OriginalImg.scene, OriginalImg.camera, target );

    calculateClickedPointColor(OriginalImgRenderer, realClickedCanvasX, realClickedCanvasY);
    projectRayAndGetIntersectedObject();
}

function animate() {


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    OriginalImg.animate();
    SegmentImg.animate();


}
```

Then we have InitCanvas.js which is the Prototype which joins the div, with the canvas and the model being loaded:

```
// this class handles the load and the canva for a nrrd
// Using programming based on prototype: https://javascript.info/class
// This class should be improved:
//   - Canvas Width and height

InitCanvas = function (IdDiv, Filename) {


    this.IdDiv = IdDiv;
    this.Filename = Filename
}

InitCanvas.prototype = {

    constructor: InitCanvas,

    init: function () {

        this.container = document.getElementById(this.IdDiv);

        // this should be changed.
        this.container.innerHeight = 600;
        this.container.innerWidth = 800;

        //These statenments should be changed to improve the image position
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.container.innerWidth / this.container.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
        this.camera.position.z = 300;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(this.camera);

        // light

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);


        // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            this.container.innerWidth = sliceZ.iLength;
            this.container.innerHeight = sliceZ.jLength;

            sliceZ.mesh.material.color.setRGB(0, 1, 1);


           // console.log('Our slice is: ', sliceZ);

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
        }.bind(this));


        this.scene = scene;


        // renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.container.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.innerWidth, this.container.innerHeight);

        // add canvas in container
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


    },

    animate: function () {

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

}
```

Plus we have the functions being used when we click the Mouse, into OnDocumentMouseDown():

```
let projectRayAndGetIntersectedObject = function () {
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse.clone(), OriginalImg.camera);
    var objects = raycaster.intersectObjects(OriginalImg.scene.children);

    console.log(objects);
};

let calculateClickedPointWindowCoordinates = function (event) {
    let realClickedCanvasX = event.offsetX;
    let realClickedCanvasY = event.offsetY;
    return {realClickedCanvasX, realClickedCanvasY};
};

let calculateNormalizedClickedPointCoordinates = function (event) {
    let OriginalImgRenderer = OriginalImg.renderer;
    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - OriginalImgRenderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / OriginalImgRenderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( ( event.clientY - OriginalImgRenderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / OriginalImgRenderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1
    return OriginalImgRenderer;
};

let calculateClickedPointColor = function (OriginalImgRenderer, realClickedCanvasX, realClickedCanvasY) {
    var target = OriginalImgRenderer.getRenderTarget();
    console.log('Our target which should be a WebGLRenderTarget is: ');
    console.log(target);

    var outputBuffer = new Uint8Array(OriginalImgRenderer.width * OriginalImgRenderer.height * 4);

    OriginalImgRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels(target, 0, 0, OriginalImgRenderer.width, OriginalImgRenderer.height, outputBuffer);

    var pixelIndex = ((realClickedCanvasX * OriginalImgRenderer.width) + realClickedCanvasY) * 4;

    var color = {
        r: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 0],
        g: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 1],
        b: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 2],
        a: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 3]
    };

    console.log('Color of clicked pixel is: ');
    console.log(color);
};
```

I have no clue about how could we fix this issue.

EDIT:3

Thank you @TheJim01 your example code solved the problem, here I show the one I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>

    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/NRRDLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Volume.js"></script>
    <script src="js/VolumeSlice.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="view" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px black solid;"></canvas>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /**********************/
    /*   Initialization   */
    /**********************/

    let realClickedCanvasX, realClickedCanvasY, clickCount=0;

    var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(500 * 500 * 4);

    function testPixelBuffer() {
        var x, y, r, g, b, a, i1, i2;
        i1 = realClickedCanvasX * size.width;
        i2 = i1 + realClickedCanvasY;
        i2 *= 4;
        r = pixelBuffer[i2 + 0];
        g = pixelBuffer[i2 + 1];
        b = pixelBuffer[i2 + 2];
        a = pixelBuffer[i2 + 3];
            console.log(i2, r, g, b, a);


    }

    document.getElementById('view').addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
        clickCount++;
        realClickedCanvasX = event.offsetX;
        realClickedCanvasY = event.offsetY;
        console.log('You have clicked on: ' + realClickedCanvasY
            + ' , ' + realClickedCanvasY +
            ' it is the click number: ' +
            clickCount);
        testPixelBuffer();
    }

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: document.getElementById("view"),
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
    });

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 50;

    camera.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity));

    scene.add(camera);

    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener("change", render);

    /**********************/
    /* Populate the Scene */
    /**********************/

    let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
    loader.load('models/nrrd/columnasegmentado01.nrrd', function (volume) {
        //z plane
        let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));
        scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
    });

    /**********************/
    /*   Render Function  */
    /**********************/

    var externalTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget();
    var size = renderer.getSize();
    externalTarget.setSize(size.width, size.height);

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        renderer.render(scene, camera, externalTarget);
    }

    render();

    /**********************/
    /*   Animation Loop   */
    /**********************/

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(externalTarget, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, pixelBuffer);
        controls.update();
    }

    animate();

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have clicked on the following zones:

[image]

And the result were:

```
    You have clicked on: 81 , 81 it is the click number: 1
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 194324 0 0 0 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 94 , 94 it is the click number: 2
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 440376 23 23 23 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 150 , 150 it is the click number: 3
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 246600 23 23 23 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 195 , 195 it is the click number: 4
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 122780 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 210 , 210 it is the click number: 5
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 12840 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 310 , 310 it is the click number: 6
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 69240 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 271 , 271 it is the click number: 7
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 255084 255 255 255 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 360 , 360 it is the click number: 8
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 495440 23 23 23 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 318 , 318 it is the click number: 9
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 511272 23 23 23 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 291 , 291 it is the click number: 10
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 685164 92 92 92 255
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 283 , 283 it is the click number: 11
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 963132 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 180 , 180 it is the click number: 12
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 960720 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 174 , 174 it is the click number: 13
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 864696 0 0 0 0
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:51 You have clicked on: 216 , 216 it is the click number: 14
    index.html?_ijt=uvc1m089ec37ho5kobp4qir885:40 510864 46 46 46 255
```

I wonder why regions 2, 3 are logged as being with the same color!

I also wonder why zones 4,5,6 are logged as they are of equal color!.

I do not fully understand the following code in your example:

```
function testPixelBuffer() {
        var x, y, r, g, b, a, i1, i2;
        i1 = realClickedCanvasX * size.width;
        i2 = i1 + realClickedCanvasY;
        i2 *= 4;
```

*Could you help me please?*

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels)

This gives you access to the render target's buffer, much like how you would read the data directly from a 2D canvas's `ImageData` buffer.

```
// re-usable objects defined outside your mouse event
var size = renderer.getSize();
var reusableTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(renderer.width, renderer.height);

// inside your mouse event...
var target = renderer.getRenderTarget() || reusableTarget;

size = renderer.getSize();
target.setSize(size.width, size.height);

renderer.render( scene, camera, target );

var outputBuffer = new Uint8Array( width * height * 4 );

renderer.readRenderTargetPixels( target, 0, 0, width, height, outputBuffer );

var pixelIndex = ((mousePosition.y * width) + mousePosition.x) * 4;

var color = {
  r: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 0],
  g: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 1],
  b: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 2],
  a: outputBuffer[pixelIndex + 3]
};
```

**EDIT:**

You're right, you have to render to an external render target. I've edited my code above.

If you're getting errors when trying to render to an external render target, I think that's worthy of creating a separate question (it goes beyond the scope of "how to I get a pixel color at x,y"). Do reference/link to this question, so readers can get the whole story.

Once the render target issue is resolved, this issue will likely become resolved in the process.

**Adding a snippet-based test:**

I'm honestly not sure why you're getting the results you're getting. Below you can find a simple snippet that implements `readRenderTargetPixels`, and succeeds.

(Open the Dev Console in your browser to see the results.)

```js
/**********************/
/*   Initialization   */
/**********************/

var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array( 500 * 500 * 4 );
function testPixelBuffer () {
 var x, y, r, g, b, a, i1, i2;
 for ( x = 0; x < size.width; ++x ) {
  i1 = x * size.width;
  for ( y = 0; y < size.height; ++y ) {
   i2 = i1 + y;
   i2 *= 4;
   r = pixelBuffer[ i2 + 0 ];
   g = pixelBuffer[ i2 + 1 ];
   b = pixelBuffer[ i2 + 2 ];
   a = pixelBuffer[ i2 + 3 ];
   if ( a > 0 ) {
    console.log( i2, r, g, b, a );
        console.count("Colored pixels count:");
   }
  }
 }
}
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", testPixelBuffer);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
 canvas: document.getElementById( "view" ),
 antialias: true,
 alpha: true
} );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 28, 1, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 50;

camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, Infinity ) );

scene.add( camera );

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( "change", render );

/**********************/
/* Populate the Scene */
/**********************/

var geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );

var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
 color: "red"
} );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat );

scene.add( mesh );

/**********************/
/*   Render Function  */
/**********************/

var externalTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget();
var size = renderer.getSize();
externalTarget.setSize( size.width, size.height );

function render () {
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 renderer.render( scene, camera, externalTarget );
}
render();

/**********************/
/*   Animation Loop   */
/**********************/

function animate () {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 renderer.readRenderTargetPixels( externalTarget, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, pixelBuffer );
 controls.update();
}
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge">
 <title>TEST</title>

 <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
 <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

 <input id="test" value="Test Pixel Buffer" type="button" /><br />

 <canvas id="view" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px black solid;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I have edited the question, and now Render Target is right, however the colors are all undefined!

Comment: @Enoy I've added a snippet to test checking pixels using `readRenderTargetPixels`. Please cross-check it against you implementation. If the code looks OK, you may still need to open another topic on why your values are undefined.

Comment: Thank you @TheJim01 for your great help. Your answer solved the problem. I would like you could explain in you code why do you put i1 and i2. I mean, why do you need to add/multiply to x,y the size.width? I have edited the question to show what code worked for me. Plus some pictures about what have I tried to understand how colors are detected and to verify if they are good detected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Enoy I used `i1` and `i2` simply so I would only have to do the math of mapping a 2D coordinate into a 1D index once, rather than for every color value. [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid) covers the 2D (screen coordinates) to 1D (`pixelBuffer`) mapping really well. I multiply the final value by `4` because there are 4 values per pixel (RGBA). Pixel index `1` actually covers indices `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7` in `pixelBuffer`.